# joint uniform distribution of two RV

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions

i got two continuous R.V $X,Y$ 
their joint density  is uniformly distributed in a bounded triangle, between the x,y axis and y = -x +1.

lets mark the joint density   as $f$.

is it true that $f = 2 $ if $(x,y)$ is in the triangle
and $0$ otherwise?

Comment: Yes, that is correct but how did you arrive at the answer?

Comment: the area of the triangle is 1/2, so the probability that (x,y) is in the triangle is 1/(1/2) = 2.

Comment: by the way, it not seems weird that now, after i got the joint density , after i calculate the density  for X, it is also constant function of 2? and so on for Y?

Comment: No, _probabilities_ cannot have value $2$. So, what exactly does that $2$ mean? It is _not_ "the probability that (x,y) is in the triangle.

Comment: indeed! WTF. my bad.

Comment: The individual densities are not constant, a look at the picture shows that the "weight" of $X$ is concentrated towards small values. Same for $Y$.

Answer (score 1):

Let be $T(x,y)=\{(x,y)\in\Bbb R^2: x+y\le 1, x\ge 0, y\ge 0\}$ the triangle. If $f(x,y)$ is uniform over $T$, then
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases} k & (x,y)\in T\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}
$$
with $k\ge 0$ and $$\iint_T k\operatorname{d}\!x\operatorname{d}\!y=1.$$
But
$$\iint_T 1\operatorname{d}\!x\operatorname{d}\!y=\text{area}(T)=\frac{1}{2}$$
Thus, $\frac{1}{2}k=1$ and $k=2$, so that
$$
f(x,y)=\begin{cases} 2 & (x,y)\in T\\
0 & \text{otherwise}\end{cases}.
$$
The marginal densities $f_X(x)$ and $f_Y(y)$ are
$$
f_X(x)=\int_0^{1-x}2\operatorname{d}\!y=2(1-x)\qquad 0\le x\le 1
$$
and
$$
f_Y(y)=\int_0^{1-y}2\operatorname{d}\!x=2(1-y)\qquad 0\le y\le 1.
$$
Note that $X$ and $Y$ are not independent $f_{X,Y}(x,y)\neq f_X(x)\cdot f_Y(y)$.

Comment: great. thanks for the formalization. but how i can now find the density  of X, and Y?

Comment: @AmitArie Just edited